# Displaying images in email by default

Tags: css, email, html-email, mailchimp

I just sent a test email using mailchimp of an EDM I have custom designed coded. Everything works fine except the images won't display unless I specifically click 'display images'. I'm viewing in gmail on firefox. This is strange considering other emails that get sent to me have images displayed automatically. Is this anything to do with coding or some setting in Mailchimp?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Grill10 | Results</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="background:#3b4040;
                   padding-bottom: 100px;">

                <!-- HEADER -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="90px" width="100%" id="bodyTable" align= "center" style="background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, #f00439, #f28d0d);" >
                        <img src="http://www.robertkoh.net/grill10site/img/g10logoEDM.png">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <!-- ____ COMPLETED THE QUIZ -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="40px" width="100%" align= "center" style="display:inline-block;
                                                                          color:white;
                                                                          font-family:arial;
                                                                          font-size: 20px;
                                                                          margin-top: 20px;"
                                                                           >


                        <p id="username" style="display:inline-block;
                                                font-weight: bold;
                                                color:white;
                                                font-family:arial;">Janet</p>
                                                completed the quiz:
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <!-- QUIZ NAME -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="60px" width="100%" align= "center" style=
                                                                    "

                                                                    color:white;
                                                                    font-family:arial;
                                                                    font-size: 25px;
                                                                    text-transform: uppercase;
                                                                    line-height: 30px;
                                                                    padding-left: 10px;
                                                                    padding-right:10px;" >


                        <p id="quizname" style="display:inline-block;
                                                ">LAKERS FRANCHISE HISTORY REALLY LONG TITLE</p>

                       </td>
                </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>
              <table align="center" >
                <tr>
                  <td id= "scorebox" width= "80%" align="center" style="
                                                                                      color:white;
                                                                                      font-family:arial;
                                                                                      font-size: 25px;
                                                                                      line-height: 10px;
                                                                                      padding-bottom: 20px;
                                                                                      padding-left: 10px;
                                                                                      padding-right: 10px;
                                                                                      vertical-align: middle;">
                    <p id="username" style="font-weight:bold;display:inline-block;">JANET SMORTHSENWORTH</p> SCORED 8/10
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>


                <!-- PROMPT -->

          <tr>
            <td>
              <table align="center" >
                <tr>
                  <td id= "scorebox" width= "80%" align="center" style="
                                                                                      color:white;
                                                                                      font-family:arial;
                                                                                      font-size: 20px;
                                                                                      line-height: 28px;
                                                                                      padding-bottom: 20px;
                                                                                      padding-left: 10px;
                                                                                      padding-right: 10px;
                                                                                      vertical-align: middle;">Think you can do better? Click below to try yourself!
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>

                <!-- CTA BUTTON -->
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
                            <table height="50px" width="280px" align= "center" style="background: #68c357;
                                                                                      border-bottom: 6px solid #009d22;
                                                                                      color:white;
                                                                                      font-family:arial;
                                                                                      text-decoration: none;
                                                                                      ">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align= "center">
                                        GRILL ME
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                 </tr> 

                 <!-- SOCIAL -->
                 <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.robertkoh.net/grill10site/img/fbEDM.png" style="margin-top: 40px; margin-right: 13px;"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.robertkoh.net/grill10site/img/twitterEDM.png"></a>
                    </td>
                 </tr>        
            </table>


        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible. but in your own gmail account you could  set it to always display images from it.

Comment: Yeah, that's a client's security measure, I don't think you can do anything about the client's preferences to not display images as default.

Answer (score 1):

There is literally nothing on your end (as the sender) that you can do about image blocking. It is a default setting client-side and is controlled by the user/recipient.

This is a security measure used by many email clients to help protect their users from potential malicious attacks via downloaded files/images.  There have been many now that use a cached image system that allows the images to be downloaded in a sandbox server by the email client that then scans the file for any potential issues. By doing this, it allows the images to be safely displayed to the recipient automatically as they would download from the vetted sandbox and not direct from the unprotected source.

If you, personally, want your Gmail to display images automatically, please go here for instructions: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/145919?hl=en

Comment: Thanks, yeh I understand it's a security measure by the email client. But why does it only apply to the test email I sent myself via mailchimp and not emails received by others? For example all the spam emails I get from Facebook, or nba.com all display images automatically without me having to activate them.

Comment: It likely is from the setting on your client.